# Does Apache POI 4.0.x support Java 11

Tags: java, apache-poi, java-11

Came to know that Java 11 no longer supports property "java.version" in it.

So does Apache POI 4.0.x support Java 11 as it contains java.version property?

If not, can I know the future release of compatible poi with Java 11?
If not any best alternative to replace the POI in Java 11?

Got the source code of POI 4.0.x and found the trace of property "java.version" in it.

Comment: Did you actually try using it? What didn't work for you in that case? Can you share the error/stack trace?

Comment: I didn't use 4.0 but it worked with 3.9 with JDK11

Comment: Where did you read that `java.version` is no longer supported? `System.getProperty("java.version")` works fine for me running on Java 11